# Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I took a default  asp.net core with an angular  template in visual studio 2019, and I build it, then show this output, now I don't understand

`1>Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes...
1>npm WARN deprecated @angular/http@6.1.10: Switch to @angular/common/http - see https://angular.io/guide/http
1>npm WARN deprecated istanbul@0.4.5: This module is no longer maintained, try this instead:
1>npm WARN deprecated   npm i nyc
1>npm WARN deprecated Visit https://istanbul.js.org/integrations for other alternatives.`

I can not build my project and exit from visual studio,

Comment: Wait for it to complete. If it is stuck ("several minutes" have been elapsed) then end VS in Task Manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is stuck in Visual Studio try to close it. After that go in into the `ClientApp` folder and remove `node_modules` to avoid having some stuck in packages. After that call `npm install` in command line from the root of `ClientApp`. This way you will be able to see on the console if there is some progress while the command is running.

`npm install` will take some minutes depending on your PC performance and network connection.

Comment: Thank you. This occurred because of slow internet.